# Using the "OR" alternative in writing Prolog rules

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a simple prolog rule that checks if a given person from a database has ever sent or received a message to or from another person in that database. The fact is based in the form of message(sender, receiver, date). The code I have is;

```
?-message(max, X, Y) ; message(A, max, B).
```

The problem is, only the first combination of the OR alternative ";" is tried, and I receive that values of X and Y, But the program stops there without executing the second combination of the OR alternative, and i receive no values for A and B. I just need some advice to know if I am going about this the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: You need to press `;`, or space, or tab, to receive alternative answers upon backtracking. There is nothing wrong with your query!

Answer (score 1):

As soon as the first message matches, your rule is satisfied; it would only need to consider the second message if the first failed.  If you want both to be used, you want an and (, instead of ;).

Comment: Thanks. I just tried using the "AND" combination and it worked. If there is more than one message either sent or received by max, is there a way of displaying all of them instead of just one in each direction?

Comment: This is a misleading answer; the second part of the disjunction will be evaluated upon backtracking.

Comment: what answer are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The disjunction pushes a choice point to the query. To explore all choice points, you can do two things:

- ask for more answers by pressing `;`, or SPACE, or TAB.
- collect all answers using a predicate like for example `findall/3` or `bagof/3`.

For example, with these messages defined:

```
message(max, fred, 3).
message(max, fred, 4).
message(fred, max, 1).
message(fred, scott, 2).
message(max, scott, 5).
```

And your query, and backtracking:

```
?- message(max, To, Time) ; message(From, max, Time).
To = fred,
Time = 3 ;
To = fred,
Time = 4 ;
To = scott,
Time = 5 ;
Time = 1,
From = fred.
```

Keep in mind that your query is more or less the same as a predicate:

```
person_message(From, to(To, Time)) :-
    message(From, To, Time).
person_message(To, from(From, Time)) :-
    message(From, To, Time).
```

With this defined:

```
?- person_message(max, M).
M = to(fred, 3) ;
M = to(fred, 4) ;
M = to(scott, 5) ;
M = from(fred, 1).

?- bagof(M, person_message(max, M), Message).
Message = [to(fred, 3), to(fred, 4), to(scott, 5), from(fred, 1)].
```

Comment: Thanks. I get everything uptill M = to(fred, 3);. how did you get M?

Comment: @Hustl3r28 I typed it into the interpreter? Your question is unclear.